# PostgreSQL regex

Tags: postgresql

I need to get similarity between two texts abc_0 and abc_[0-9].
I am able to find similarity when I do: 
select  'abc_0' ~ 'abc_[0-9]' returns true
but 
select  'abc_[0-9]' ~ 'abc_0' returns false. I need this to return true.

Comment: why do you need that operand order?

Comment: Hey Jasen ! The left hand side will be my input text from UI. e.g in select 'abc_[0-9]' ~ 'abc_0', abc_[0-9] will be my input from UI. So suppose I have saved 'abc_0.csv' in DB, I should not allow abc_[0-9].csv because its similar to abc_0.csv

Comment: `select 'found' from TABLENAME where   column ~ 'USERINPUT' or 'USERINPUT' ~ column`  -- but likely to give error more often than results, also `'abc_[0-9]' ~  'abc_[0-9]'` is false.

Comment: Note that the `~` operator explicitly compares the left hand input to a pattern defined in the right-hand input. If you're trying to see if the literal string "abc_[0-9].csv" is similar to the literal string "abc_0.csv", you'd have to convert the second literal string to a pattern of some sort, and you'd have to thus define what qualifies as "similar". PostgreSQL has a `SIMILAR` operator, but it also compares your left value (a literal string) to your right value (a pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Right syntax is

```
SELECT string_variable ~ regexp_mask
```

It returns `true` if and only if `string_variable` matches `regexp_mask`.

In first example

```
SELECT 'abc_0' ~ 'abc_[0-9]'
```

`regexp_mask` is `'abc_[0-9]'`. Such example will check if string `'abc_0'` contains text `'abc_'` and then 1 digit symbol from interval `[0-9]`.

In second example

```
SELECT 'abc_[0-9]' ~ 'abc_0'
```

`regexp_mask` is `'abc_0'` It checks if string `'abc_[0-9]'` contains text `'abc_0'`. But it has a brace `[` between `abc_` and `0`, that's why such check returns `false`.

In first example braces `[]` means interval, in second - text.

Answer (score 0):

> select 'abc_[0-9]' ~ 'abc_0' returns false

Of course it does.

Does the string value consisting of the characters ...

```
{ 'a', 'b', 'c', '_', '[', '0', '-', '9', ']' }
```

... match the Regular Expression "abc_0"?  No, it doesn't.

*Why* do you need this? 
You cannot simply "invent" SQL syntax.

If there are files involved, would it not be better to check whether the file already exists or not, regardless of what it may or may not be called?

Comment: You can invent new operators.  It would be easy to define one that does what he wants.  There are some cases where it might even be useful, not just possible.